# Windows/Linux/Mac: Detecting Android (as an accessory) when connected

Tags: android, linux, usb, libusb-win32

I want to be able to detect when an Android device is connected to the computer.

As "Android" is a collection of devices with varying vendor/product IDs, how are we able to identify if a product is an Android device upon USB connection?

To make matters worse, the Android device class can be different too (phone, tablets, cameras, etc)

For what it's worth, I'm using libusb-win32 (based on libusb-0.1)

Comment: You should probably base this around what you hope to *do* with the Android device - ie, move files, do ADB debugging operations, tether to it, operate it in Android Accessory mode, etc.